# Error:module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'STEREO_BM_BASIC_PRESET'

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, color-depth

I am trying to get the depth map of two stereo images but error 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'STEREO_BM_BASIC_PRESET' occurred.
the code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
# Convert to depth image

imgL = cv2.imread('D:\Books\Pav Man\PICS\R.jpg',0)
imgR = cv2.imread('D:\Books\Pav Man\PICS\L.jpg',0)

stereo = cv2.StereoBM(cv2.STEREO_BM_BASIC_PRESET,ndisparities=16, SADWindowSize=15)
disparity = stereo.compute(imgL,imgR)
plt.imshow(disparity,'gray')
plt.show()
#-------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved worked with OpenCV 4.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
# Convert to depth image

imgL = cv2.imread('D:\Books\Pav Man\PICS\R.jpg',0)
imgR = cv2.imread('D:\Books\Pav Man\PICS\L.jpg',0)

stereo = cv2.StereoBM_create(numDisparities=16, blockSize=15)

disparity = stereo.compute(imgL,imgR)

plt.imshow(disparity,'gray')

plt.show()
```